# Socket.IO Angular Server to Server Connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, server

Is it possible to do a simple socket.io connection on a client server running in gulp to a other server running in node?

```
    .--------.      .----------.      .----------.
    |SERVER A|      |          |      | SERVER B |
    | (Gulp) |      |  CLIENT  |      | (Nodejs) |
    |  PORT  | <--> |   SIDE   | <--> |   PORT   |
    |  2772  |      |          |      |   8000   |
    '--------'      '----------'      '----------'
```

I tried to use the `socket.io-client` but I'm a bit confused.. but I use it like this:

#### Server.js

```
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
    var client = ioClient.connect( "http://localhost:" + 2772 );

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected')
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("a user disconnected")
      });
    });

     client.on('connection', function(socket){
       console.log('a user connected')
       client.on('disconnect', function(){
         console.log("a user disconnected")
       });
     });
```

In my Angular..

#### App.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('ngclient', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ui.select','ngSanitize', 'btford.socket-io']);
```

#### Controller

```
    myApp.controller('dailydoseController', ['$scope', 'chatSocket', function($scope, chatSocket){


    }]);
```

#### Factory

```
myApp.factory('chatSocket', ['socketFactory', function(socketFactory){


   return socketFactory;
}]);
```

Its just the relevant... the entire code is too long.. Please help

Comment: I'm confused... Why are you calling "Angular" Server A? Angular is all client-side. it looks like you need a simple client->server socket connection.

Comment: Sorry, is the gulp server

Comment: right, but gulp isn't making socket connections, the client is. gulp just serves up static html/js/css/images. So, you want to make a connection from CLIENT to SERVER B

Comment: You could give us a direct link to where socketFactory came from, as well as how you are using it. Did you include the socket-io.js being served from your socket server on your client html page? it seems like you completely missed part of the tutorial.

Comment: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LkheOr8LuY)                          This is the video..

Comment: Yes, I've include everything on my partial(html page)..  socket-io.js, socket.js and socket.io-1.3.5.js.. All its on my libs folder and included on my html page..

Comment: not the socket-io.js from your client code, the one your node.js server (SERVER B) should be serving. the client one will work if used properly, but using th eone from SERVER B would make connecting as easy as executing `io()` or `io.connect()`. Otherwise, you'll have to pass options in to give the server location/port in addition to the namespace you're subscribing to.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I already have it too..

Comment: now we just need to see the controller code that uses the chatSocket service.

Comment: its up there... empty too.

Comment: uhm... if it's empty... what are you trying to do. shouldn't you be... sending messages, or listening for messages? otherwise, how do you know it's working or not working?  you haven't even executed the factory so it can connect.

Comment: Ok, if you watch the video there is a part when he runs the server the first time, and on console shows the message "a user connected", I want to get to that point but isn't works because the two separated servers...

Sorry I think I forgot to say this... The Angular server is in folder:

App/Angular/

and the Node server is in:

App/Services/

Comment: you have to execute the factory function for it to connect. sorry, i'm not watching a video-based programming tutorial, you can't copy paste from a video... seems kinda... weird.

Comment: This is the step you missed: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#making-a-socket-instance

Comment: Right, I already have that.. I mean the communication between app, controller, and factory its ok.. but to SERVER B doesnt.

Comment: No, you're missing a `()` in the snippet labeled "Factory" above. hence, the problem with using a youtube tutorial for code.. makes creating typos easy.

Comment: Yeah sorry, but didn't works :'(

Comment: check console for socket connections. enable socket.io debug mode.

Comment: Have you made a simple non-angular test to make sure your socket server is even working? http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: No, it didn't.. Yes, I have a Chat App on the same folder in public.. working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79437/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-jhony-blaze).

Comment: ok.. When you want..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79809/discussion-between-jhony-blaze-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question.

In the client side (Angular in your case) you can use client implementation of socket.io (or with Angular component implementing socket-io client https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io).

In your node server, you should use server component of socket-io like the following one.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // handle connection
})
```

Consider that even tough websocket are bidirectional, we still have a 'client' and the 'server'. In your case the 'client' is Angular running on the browser and the 'server' is node.
The node server cannot open the websocket directly with the client because the WebSockets API on the browser does not provide a way to listen for connections.

Hope it helps!